# How to Remove Li element whose Ol child has no Li in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

With this given code below, I would like to remove any 'li' element whose child `ol` element does contain any `li` element, yet with no avail.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myUL li').each(function() {
    var lenLi = $(this).find('ol').children('li').length;
    if (lenLi == 0) {
      $(this).remove();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol id="myUL">
  <li>Hello 1</li>
  <li>Hello 2
    <ol></ol>
  </li>
  <li>Hello 3
    <ol>
      <li>Hello 3.1</li>
      <li>Hello 3.2</li>
      <li>Hello 3.3</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

after executing code above, Hello 1, Hello 2 were removed. However, children of Hello 3 were all removed as well.

My question is why was that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector `#myUL li` is also selecting the `li`s in Hello 3 because they are `li` descendants of `#myUL` and since they have no `ol` with `li` in them they get removed. 
You can use the child selector `>` to only select the children of `#myUL`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myUL > li').each(function() {
    var lenLi = $(this).find('ol').children('li').length;
    if (lenLi == 0) {
      $(this).remove();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol id="myUL">
  <li>Hello 1</li>
  <li>Hello 2
    <ol></ol>
  </li>
  <li>Hello 3
    <ol>
      <li>Hello 3.1</li>
      <li>Hello 3.2</li>
      <li>Hello 3.3</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is iterating through all `li` contained within`#myUL`. Use a first-level child selector `>`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myUL > li').each(function() {
    var lenLi = $(this).find('ol').children('li').length;
    if (lenLi == 0) {
      $(this).remove();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol id="myUL">
  <li>Hello 1</li>
  <li>Hello 2
    <ol></ol>
  </li>
  <li>Hello 3
    <ol>
      <li>Hello 3.1</li>
      <li>Hello 3.2</li>
      <li>Hello 3.3</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#el').is(':empty')){
  // custom code
}
```

More info [here](https://api.jquery.com/is/)

Comment: this does not take into account the ol element containing white-space or other element beside `li` element. Ex. if Hello 2 like this   `<li>Hello 2
    <ol>   </ol>
  </li>` Hello 2 will not be removed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use query selector `#myUL li ol` for find ol and check li inside it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myUL li ol').each(function() {
    var lenLi = $(this).find('li').length;
    console.log(lenLi);
    if (lenLi == 0) {
      $(this).remove();
    }
  })
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myUL li ol').each(function() {
    var lenLi = $(this).find('li').length;
    console.log(lenLi);
    if (lenLi == 0) {
      $(this).remove();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol id="myUL">
  <li>Hello 1</li>
  <li>Hello 2
    <ol></ol>
  </li>
  <li>Hello 3
    <ol>
      <li>Hello 3.1</li>
      <li>Hello 3.2</li>
      <li>Hello 3.3</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```